# Accessing ancestor values in xpath with Solr DataImportHandler

Tags: xpath, solr

If my xml is structured like so:

```
<fruit>
<apple appleId="apple_1">
 <core coreId="core_1">
  <seed>1</seed>
  <seed>2</seed>
 </core>
</apple>
<apple appleId="apple_2">
 <core coreId="core_1">
  <seed>1</seed>      
 </core>
</apple>
</fruit>
```

and I want the seeds to be the documents in my solr schema, how can I access the appleId and coreId?

Here's the pertinent entity definition from my data-config.xml:

```
<entity name="apples"
            processor="XPathEntityProcessor"
            stream="true"
            forEach="/fruit/apple/core/seed"
            url="fruit.xml"
            transformer="script:create_id"
            >
    <field column="seed_s" xpath="/fruit/apple/core/seed" />
    <field column="apple_id_s" xpath="/fruit/apple/@appleId" />
</entity>
```

script:create_id creates a unique id for each seed.

In this example, apple_id_s is coming back as null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. I need to use commonField="true" and make sure to loop through each apple and core. Also, I need to set the pk="seed_s" which triggers solr to store the document.

Here's my new entity definition:

```
<entity name="apples"
        processor="XPathEntityProcessor"
        stream="true"
        pk="seed_s"
        forEach="/fruit/apple/core/seed | /fruit/apple | /fruit/apple/core"
        url="fruit.xml"
        transformer="script:create_id"
        >
<field column="seed_s" xpath="/fruit/apple/core/seed" />
<field column="apple_id_s" xpath="/fruit/apple/@appleId" commonField="true"/>
<field column="core_id_s" xpath="/fruit/apple/core/@coreId" commonField="true"/>
```